# My Windows Authentication user has been disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I accidently disabled my `Windows Authentication` login and I don't have `sa` login (or other admin login).

How I can login to sql server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this: [Troubleshooting: Connecting to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx):

> Resolution
>
> Start the instance of SQL Server in single-user mode by using either
>   the `-m` or `-f` options. Any member of the computer's local
>   Administrators group can then connect to the instance of SQL Server as
>   a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.